# JavaScript matching id with form input elements id

Tags: javascript, html

A simple html form with some JavaScript validations

log true if the form input id matches the id from array  objects otherwise log false

the problem with the script is that it is matching with the last input id only

//see the demo here

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

function formElements(inputs) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onfocus = function(e) {
      if (e.target.id === inputs.id) {
        console.log(true)
      } else {
        console.log(false);
      }
    }
  }
}

function setMsg() {
  let errorMsg = [{
      'id': 'fname',
      'msg': 'first name is required'
    },
    {
      'id': 'lname',
      'msg': 'last name is required'
    }
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < errorMsg.length; i++) {
    formElements(errorMsg[i]);
  }
}

setMsg();
```

```html
<form method="get" id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
  
        </div>
  
  <button type="submit" name="send">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please use the _"Tidy"_ button in the snippet editor. And please have a look at [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) -> The html section is supposed to only contain the content of the `<body>` element.

Comment: While looping over the error messages you assign the `onfocus` property. By doing this you overwrite the function with each error message.

Comment: Every time you call `formElements`, you are _overwriting_ the event handler assigned to `items[i].onfocus` with a new one. This is all "bass ackwards" anyway, you should not try and add X event handler functions, one for each entry in your errorMsg array - you should add one handler function, and then inside of that, loop over your data.

Comment: @CBroe how? can u please show the demo?

Comment: I can't currently see much sense in what you are trying to do here. You are not actually validating anything (your error messages say the field is required - but you are not checking whether it actually contains anything, anywhere?) And returning a true or false for each field individually, what would be the point of that? Usually you'd want _one_ boolean return value for the _whole_ validation, so that based on that you can decide whether to allow submitting the form, or not. Can you please clarify what you _actually_ need here first of all?

Comment: @CBroe  first of all I just want to check whether input id is equal to id in array object if they match  log true other ways false then , if input (actually  form fields) are empty  show error messages

Comment: It makes little sense to loop over two sets of data here. Either loop over your input elements, and then find the corresponding error message via ID in your array, or do it the other way around, loop over your array, and assign an event handler to each input field selected via the ID value from your array.

Comment: @CBroe show the code please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236641/discussion-between-william-williams-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1):

Looping over both the elements and the error messages, makes little sense IMHO. Decide on one or the other.

I made your array into an object here, that uses the field ID as key - that makes it easier to look up if an error message for a field is set.

And then we simply loop over all input fields, check if an error message exists under its ID - and if so, attach a focus handler that alerts the corresponding error message. (No validation of any kind implemented yet, it will always alert the message when the field receives focus.)

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

function formElements(errorMsg){
  for(let i= 0; i < items.length; i ++){
    if(errorMsg[items[i].id]) {
      items[i].onfocus = function() {
        alert(errorMsg[this.id]);
      }
    }
  }  
}

let errorMsg = {
  fname: 'first name is required',
  lname: 'last name is required'
};

formElements(errorMsg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" id="myForm">
<div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
</div>
<button type="submit" name="send">send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**What is happening in you code?**

From your `setMsg` function you are calling `formElements` function in a loop.

`formElements` function loops through the list of inputs and registers `onfocus` events for each inputs. You have two inputs one with `#fname` and `#lname`. Each time when `formElements` fumction is executed, it registers a new `onfocus` event to those two inputs by clearing the previous `onfocus` event.

**Execution of `setMsg` function**

When the `formElements` function is executed for the first index of `setMsg` function, i.e, with parameter `{ 'id': 'fname', 'msg': 'first name is required' }`, it registers an onfocus event to both inputs `#fname` and `#lname`. This `onfocus` event checks whether the id of each input is `fname` when they are being focused.

When the `formElements` function is executed for the second index of `setMsg` function, i.e, with parameter `{ 'id': 'lname', 'msg': 'last name is required' }`, your actual `onfocus` event will be registered. i.e, it will updated the `onfocus` event registerd on the last itration that mentioned above. The new `onfocus` event check for each input whether they have id `lname`. If the id is not `lname`, it will logs `false`, else it will log `true`.

The below is **your code snippet with some debug logs** added. In the below example you can see that the onfocus event for `fname` and `lname` check whether its id is `lname`. Thats why your focus is working as expected for second input only

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
function formElements(inputs) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log('Im registering focus event for                  #', items[i].id);
    console.log('I will check the id of each input whether it is ', inputs.id);
    console.log('......................................');
    items[i].onfocus = function (e) {
      if (e.target.id === inputs.id) {
        console.log(true)
      } else {
        console.log(false);
      }
    }
  }
}
function setMsg() {
  let errorMsg = [
    { 'id': 'fname', 'msg': 'first name is required' },
    { 'id': 'lname', 'msg': 'last name is required' }
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < errorMsg.length; i++) {
    formElements(errorMsg[i]);
  }
}
setMsg();
```

```html
<form method="get" id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="send">send</button>
</form>
```

**Solution**

Your logic neest to be modified. Please find the logic that I used.

- Select all inputs with the class `form-control`.
- Keep the `errorMsg` array
- Loop through each inputs and register `onfocus` event.
- Logic used in `onfoucs`: If the id of the input is present in the `errorMsg` array, log output as `true`, else log `false`

Please find a working fiddle below. Please note I have added a third node with id `mname`, which is not there in `errorMsg` array. So forst two fields will log `true` and third will log `false`

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control'); // 3 elements will be there
let errorMsg = [
  { 'id': 'fname', 'msg': 'first name is required' },
  { 'id': 'lname', 'msg': 'last name is required' }
];
function setMsg() {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onfocus = function (e) {
      // Checking whether the id that I foucsed just now is there in the `errorMsg` array.
      const msgNode = errorMsg.find((node) => node.id === e.target.id);
      if (msgNode) {
        console.log(true)
      } else {
        console.log(false);
      }
    }
  }
}
setMsg();
```

```html
<form method="get" id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mname" name="lname">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="send">send</button>
</form>
```

**Edit**

If you want to check whether the input is empty, in the above logic on the onfocus event while checking the id exist or not, check whether the target value is defined or not, if the value is not present, logs the error message.

**Working fiddle:** I have used `onblur` instead of `onfocus`, because it provides better user expreience while logging error on blur rather than on focus. This event works good with `onfocus` aswell.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control'); // 3 elements will be there
let errorMsg = [
  { 'id': 'fname', 'msg': 'first name is required' },
  { 'id': 'lname', 'msg': 'last name is required' }
];
function setMsg() {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onblur = function (e) {
      const msgNode = errorMsg.find((node) => node.id === e.target.id);
      if (msgNode) {
        console.log(true);
        const inputValue = e.target.value;
        if (!inputValue) {
          console.error(msgNode.msg);
        }
      } else {
        console.log(false);
      }
    }
  }
}
setMsg();
```

```html
<form method="get" id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mname" name="lname">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="send">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: add also the messages if form fields are empty

Comment: sorry what about performance issue from two solutions above ?

Comment: @williamwilliams which one? the first two ones that I mentioned?

Comment: yeah  , especially when I will need to add some ajax code

Comment: @williamwilliams The first implementation have bugs, which I have corrected in my second implementation. So rather than cecking the performace, the functionality is to be coreected first right? So my second solution will be suitable for you.

Comment: thanks , let me dive into || can we chat on whatsapp ?,pls

Comment: You can ping in this thread. I will update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236646/discussion-between-william-williams-and-nitheesh).

Answer (score 0):

For every error message, you are adding event listeners of each input.

The first time you add onfocus with `id="fname"`

the second time you add them with `id="lname"`

So, in the second iteration, you are overriding the event listeners you added in your first iteration.

I would suggest this:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

function formElements(errorMsg){
items.forEach(item=>{
item.onfocus=(e)=>{
if (errorMsg.find(error=>error.id===e.target.id)
) console.log(true)
else console.log(false)
}
})

}
function setMsg(){
let errorMsg = [
{'id': 'fname', 'msg': 'first name is required'},
{'id': 'lname', 'msg': 'last name is required'}
];
 formElements(errorMsg);
       
}
setMsg()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" id="myForm">
<div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname">
</div>
<button type="submit" name="send">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the good solution  , the aim was to  display error messages only when inputs are empty